# Search an object using RGB Color model

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb, light

I want to write a code to search the Object in the color image. In this code, the user decides the range of color of the searched Object (that means the code could learn first the color of the object). Then the code search in every color image if there is an Object in this range of the color.

1. Someone told me that it is not good idea to use the RGB model in this case. He said that by using RGB model to learn the color of the Object, you will have the problem of Overlapping the colors.

   Anyone has an idea what that means? And why to lern and search the color of the object to search, should be not in RGB Model?
2. The same person told me also, that I can not use RGB Model to represent some colors like brown color. I don't understand why?
3. Why if I would use the HSI Color model, I would have a problem to search the Object if my Object is white or black? I have heard that I would have a problem by using HSI if the color of the object has a small Saturation or small Intensity.

Comment: See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49000/how-can-the-dress-optical-illusion-be-accurately-reproduced-on-other-images for examples of how hard this can be.

Comment: Quick hints (although not direct answer to your question): 1. try HSV color model instead 2. Check [histogram back projection](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html) algorithm.

Comment: if you want to work with colours go and read everything about colour spaces. then you don't have to rely on other people... there is sufficient free literature online. don't work with things you don't understand

Comment: From http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/brown-color.htm you can see that RGB can produce brown colors, like for example RGB(139,69,19)